# Pointer to a casted Pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I've come across pointers to casted pointers (not sure that this is the correct term) in C such as:

*(long *) p = 10; I could never for the life of me understand what it means, or, the other example:

*(void *) NULL, or *(char *) 0; I just can't wrap my head around it, could someone please explain this to me, and save me from partial brain damage? :)

Thanks

(P.S An example is shown below of such usage)

> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
>           char *p, *payload = (char *) malloc(1052);
>
> ```
>     p = payload;
>     memset(p, '\x90', 1052);
>
>     /* Jump 12 ahead over the trashed word from unlink() */
>     memcpy(p, "\xeb\x0c", 2);
>
>     /* We put the shellcode safely away from the possibly corrupted area */
>     p += 1020 - 64 - sizeof(shellcode);
>     memcpy(p, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode) - 1);
>
>     /* Set up the prev_size and overflow size fields */
>     p += sizeof(shellcode) + 64 - 4;
>     *(long *) p = -4;
>     p += 4;
>     *(long *) p = -16;
>
>     /* Set up the fwd and bck of the fake chunk */
>     p += 8;
>     *(long *) p = RETLOC - 12;
>     p += 4;
>     *(long *) p = RETADDR;
>
>     p += 4;
>     *(p) = '\0';
>
>     execl("./wilderness", "./wilderness", payload, NULL); }
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First break up the statement:

```
  long *q = (long*)p;
  *q = 10;
  p += 4;
```

The p argument is of type `char*`, you can only read or write 1 byte at a time through that pointer.  The cast to `long*` creates a pointer through which you can read or write 4 bytes at a time from/to the same address.  The assignment writes the bytes 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0A.  The same thing as:

```
  *p = 10;
  p++;
  *p = 0;
  p++;
  *p = 0;
  p++;
  *p = 0;
```

Depending on byte order.  After the assignment, p needs to be incremented by 4 because 4 bytes were written.

This trick is pretty common with buffers of bytes that contain non-byte data.

Comment: Said much more elegantly than myself.

Comment: long == 4 bytes on windows and 32-bit unix only.  long is 8 bytes on 64-bit unix.

Answer (score 2):

```
*(long *) p = -4;
```

Means: p is a "pointer to a long" and I am trying to assign the value to the memory referenced there. We do this because initially we said p was a char pointer, and we want to change its behavior when accessed.

Comment: So, why don't we just change it to (long *) p = -4; ? or, to assign the value to the memory that's referenced there, &(long *) p = -4?

/me is so confused about this...

Comment: But, what do you mean, by assign the value to the memory referenced there?

Comment: if we changed it to (long *)p = -4 we would be "saying set the address to -4" and &(long *)p = -4 would be saying set the address of the pointer *for* p to -4, which is not allowed AFAIK. Also setting the address of something to -4 is not allowed.

Comment: Setting unsigned values to signed values is allowed, but it'll cast -4 to 4294967292 (for a 4-byte `long` type).

Comment: Ah, I see now; ok.  And, what about when things like *(char *) NULL; crop up?

Comment: And, look below, for my comment on "p = -4L"

Comment: I dont think *(char *) NULL is a valid statement, but it would be the same, cast the thing "NULL" to a pointer to char, and then assign NULL the value of whatever the right hand side is. Now *(char *) P = NULL is just setting P to the value NULL.

Comment: Setting p = -4L is saying set the memory address stored in p to -4L which is not allowed. 
Briefly:
int p = "p will hold the value of an int"
int *p = "p will hold a memory address, whose contents can be consulted to get the value you want
&p = "give me the memory address where you are keeping p"
int i = 17; //hold the value 17
int *p; //hold a pointer to an int
*p = i; //assign the value of i into the pointer, effectively i and the value of p have the same "number" in them
i = &p //assign the memory address of p into i

Comment: http://codepad.org/iz2TSDfa uses *(unsigned int *)NULL = is_old_kernel ? 0 : 1; for example. Thanks for your help btw.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the * before the (long *) is called "dereferencing" the pointer.  It means, as @GrayWizardx says, that you're modifying the value in memory pointed to by the pointer.

Comment: Here's a Google Cache link to a good article...the main link is down currently, for some reason:

http://74.125.47.132/search?q=cache:QK0DjdclKX4J:cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/+dereferencing+pointer&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a

Comment: In order to access the variable that the pointer points to, right? ok. What about *(char *) NULL; ?

Comment: And, hmm -- why can't we just do "p = -4L" ?

Comment: @Grey, can you give an example of where that code is used?  I don't see it in the original question...

Comment: An example with *(unsigned int *) NULL: http://codepad.org/iz2TSDfa -- I just came across *(char *) NULL and *(void *) NULL in other places over time ...

Answer (score 1):

codepad.org/iz2TSDfa

This code writes four bytes of data to address zero in memory.  It is not common or accepted practice, and is not applicable on a general basis.  In other words: black magic.

I am guessing it triggers some sort of processor interrupt.

I advise you learn assembly/the computer architecture this code targets if you want to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The first star is actually dereferencing the casted pointer. Thus, *(long *) p = 10 means cast p to a pointer to long and assign -4 to the dereferenced location. Compare your examples to *p =10 .

Answer (score 0):

Its the pointer arithmetic, based on the pointer type i.e. whether its char* cPtr or int* nPtr, when you increment cPtr++ will move one byte and nPtr++ would move 4 bytes (assumimg char takes one byte and int takes 4 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

You may have an easier time when you understand the *motivation* behind your example code.

The code is manipulating 4-byte values, which is why `p` is being cast as a `long *`.  The construct `* (long *) p = -4;` allows you to set 4 bytes to `0xFFFFFFFC` with a single assignment.  If you left `p` as a `char *` you'd need four separate assignments, and you'd also need to worry about the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your platform.

So why not simply declare `p` as a `long *` in the first place?  Because the code is using pointer arithmetic to calculate the target addresses: `p += sizeof(shellcode) + 64 - 4;`  Pointer arithmetic is easy with a `char *` because adding 1 to the pointer will advance it to the next byte, just as you would expect.  Not so with pointers to other data types!  If `p` were declared as `long *p;` then `p += 4` adds **4 * `sizeof(long)`** to `p`.

Why?  Because this makes it easy to traverse a list of `long` variables:

```
long sum_of_longs(long vals[], int num)  { // 'vals[]' contains 'num' long ints.
   long *p;                                // This pointer traverses the array.
   long sum;                               // Running total.

   // Initialize 'p' to the first number in 'vals[]' and
   // increment through the array until 'num' reaches 0.
   //
   // Note that 'p' increases by 4 bytes each time in order
   // to advance to the next long.
   for (sum=0, p=vals;  num > 0;  p++, num--)
      sum += *p;

   return sum;
}
```

So, in your example, defining `p` as a `char *` makes it easy to do the pointer arithmetic in terms of bytes, and casting it to a `long *` makes the assignments easier.